# Python coding using collatz conjecture

Tags: python

I am new at coding and i am trying to do a collatz conjecture.

I think i already made it by i cant code a way to count how much "steps" it takes to the 1.

This is the code i already did.

```
n = int(input("Enter a number!"))

def lothar(n):
    print(n)
    if n == 1:
        return i
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n / 2
    else:
        n = ((n*3) + 1) 
    return lothar(n)

print(lothar(n))
```

I want to count using a while structure.

For example: in number 4 , it takes 3 steps.
4
2
1.

Comment: In `return i` where is `i` coming from?

Comment: It's the imaginary unit *i*.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to count the steps, but I've gone with removing the recursion and using a loop instead:

```py
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))

def lothar(n):
    steps = [n]
    while n > 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
        else:
            n = ((n*3) + 1) 
        steps.append(n)
    return steps

sequence = lothar(n)
print(sequence)
print(str(len(sequence)-1) + " step(s)")
```

That will return the sequence, which then means we can display the sequence and also output the amount of steps (i.e. the length of the sequence minus one).

For example:

```
Enter a number: 9
[9, 28, 14, 7, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
19 step(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `while loop` into the function, and give a `count` variable for counting.

```
n = int(input("Enter a number!"))

count = 1

def lothar(n,count):         
    while n != 1:     
        if n % 2 == 0:                
            count += 1
            n = n / 2             
        else:    
            count += 1
            n = ((n*3) + 1)    
    return count

print(lothar(n,count))
```

Because the result you want is to include 4, count will be added one more time, but if you want to count the number of `loops`, you should set count to 0 for calculation.

Comment: thank you very much, the i that i left there was because i was trying to do exactly this. THANK YOU SO SO MUCH.